# Make selectnode insensitive to uppercase or lowercase with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, selectsinglenode

I have the following XML:

```
<myfile:bookstore>
<myfile:books>
<myfile:book> Book 1</myfile:book>
<myfile:book> Book 2</myfile:book>
</myfile:books>
</myfile:bookstore>
```

And the following code to select the `<myfile:books>` node:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new 
XmlNamespaceManager(el.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("myfile", 
el.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

var node = el.SelectSingleNode(@"/myfile:bookstore/myfile:books", nsmgr);
```

How to make this work until the node name is `myfile:boOkS` or `myfile:BOOKS` insensitive to upper case and lower case?

Another question is right my namespaceManager ? Can it be more simple ?

Comment: Example if the node that i want is like:
    <myfile:booKs> OR <myfile:BOOks> I want it works for all cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`local-name()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256070(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`namespace-uri()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256466(v=vs.110).aspx) functions to return element names and namespaces in an XPath query, and then use the [`translate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256119(v=vs.110).aspx) function to lower-case the local name.

Thus the following should work:

```
var elementName = "books"; // Or whatever
var nameSpaceUri = el.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
var xpathQuery = string.Format(@"/myfile:bookstore/*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='{0}' and namespace-uri()='{1}']", elementName, nameSpaceUri);
var node = el.SelectSingleNode(xpathQuery, nsmgr);
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZrAkii).

Note that the lowercasing the return value of the [`name()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256078(v=vs.110).aspx) function should be avoided in cases like this.  E.g. you might be tempted to do the following:

```
var node = el.SelectSingleNode(@"/myfile:bookstore/*[translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'myfile:books']", nsmgr);
```

However, this **should not be used** because it hardcodes the namespace **prefix** `myfile:` inside the string literal `'myfile:books'`.  If later the input XML were modified to use a different prefix -- or no prefix at all, such as:

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://MyRootNameSpace">
  <Books>
    <Book> Book 1</Book>
    <Book> Book 2</Book>
  </Books>
</bookstore>
```

Then your XPath query would break despite the fact that the new XML is semantically identical to the old.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you!

Comment: @E.Hayes - glad to help.  If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: i dont know how

Comment: @E.Hayes - Instructions are in the link inside my comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow.  Since you're new to stackoverflow, you may want to take the [tour] which explains the mechanics of asking & answering questions here.